# Using AutoRoute 2.2.0 with Bloc MultiBlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-routes

I am following along with ResoCoder's excellent DDD Flutter course but am attempting to update the code to null-safety with the latest pubspecs. https://youtu.be/7qMADWW4gts

I have hit an issue with the latest version of AutoRoute which, since version 1.0, no longer has the ExtendedNavigator class.

From the course in app_widget.dart, Matt has the following code:

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              getIt<AuthBloc>()..add(const AuthEvent.authCheckRequested()),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Notes',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(router: app_router.Router()),
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.green[800],
          accentColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
          ),
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that the ExtendedNavigator class no longer exists in AutoRoute since null-safe version 1.0. I want to be able to use the Bloc pattern for state management but cannot figure out how to connect this to AutoRoute as described in the DDD course.

```
builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder(router: app_router.Router()),
```

The code on example on the auto_route package page tells me to hook up the router as follows:

```
final _appRouter = AppRouter()  
   ...  
  Widget build(BuildContext context){  
      return MaterialApp.router(  
             routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(...initialConfig),  
             routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),  
         ),  
  }
```

As the MaterialApp is a child of the MultiBlocProvider, I do not know how to access the MaterialApp.router as described in the auto_route example.

Answer (score 1):

Registering third party type was solution for me.

https://pub.dev/packages/injectable#Registering-third-party-types

```
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
  @singleton
  AppRouter get router  =>  AppRouter();
}
```

Then you can access AppRouter using getIt like this

```
getIt<AppRouter>()
```